# Can we write a "Single" query (like subquery/nested queries in SQL) for MongoDB collection?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am looking for a way where my application can fire a single query in MongoDB and get few records (offset, 'n' records) and total number of records(count all).
Can this be possible without loading all records from DB? I need a way to get portion of data along with count of all records in that collection?
My intent here is to load limited amount of data without adding extra load on MongoServer and require data in a single hit.
Thanks.

For example:
 public ResultSet findByAccountId(String accountId, int offset, int limit) {

```
    Query<ABC> query = ds.createQuery(entityClazz)
                                .field("accountId").equal(accountId)
                                .field("deleted").equal(false);

    List<ABC> ABCs =  query.order("modified")
                                     .offset(offset)
                                     .limit(limit)
                                     .asList();

    int total;

if(ABCs.size()==limit) {
            total = (int) getABCsCountByAccountId(accountId,offset);
 } else {
            total = ABCs.size();
        }

    return new ResultSet<ABC>(ABCs, offset, total);
}


public long getABCsCountByAccountId(String accountId, int offset) {

    Query<TestScript> query = ds.createQuery(entityClazz)
                                .field("accountId").equal(accountId)
                                .field("deleted").equal(false);
            query.offset(offset);

    long totalABCsInAccount =  query.countAll();

    log.info("totalABCsInAccount =  query.countAll(): "+totalABCsInAccount);

    return totalABCsInAccount;
}
```

Here I don't want second query to fire by making a call to another method getABCsCountByAccountId().

Comment: just to clarify what's needed:  number of elements in specific query output - just to have possibility to get all documents by chunks? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. For example, consider: Total records in DB 1000. I want single query which returns data for "limit" number of records(for eg. full data for limit=700 records only) plus count of total available records in db (i.e. 1000). Is there a way to get this in single query? Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: hmm, you can do it - but this is a kind of code smell for me - and extra load on server to handle that. So fastest is ask for number of records and then process accordingly. There is a way to handle your request - but imho is overkill.